# Mock function not called and not resolving or returning mocked value in React jest API testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I am using jest to test the axios API calls. Mocking the API is not resolving or returning a value and mock function is not called. Here is my code for API call and testing.

This is the base service file that has postData function

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

function setHeader(contentType:string, token:string|undefined) {
  return {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': contentType,
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  };
}

async function postData(path:string, contentType:string, token:string|undefined,
    payload:FormData | Record<string, any> | string) {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${API_ENDPOINT}${path}`,
    headers: setHeader(contentType, token),
    data: payload,
  });
}

export {postData}
```

This is the test file code that i have tried.

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import confirmProfile from '../../apis/onboard/confirmProfile';

jest.mock('axios');
const mockAxios=axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
const VALID_TOKEN='eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uIjoicmRjZDhpbXduOXl0YjZ5eTRrN3I4NnJsb3RjcnZ0cHkiLCJuYmYiOjE2NTI2NzYyNTguMzcwNTUyOCwiaXNzIjoiZ296ZWFsIn0.IR1hNOZPY4rcrykJgzrGkgfJM9vJNuveG-KS8BYaxnI';

it("Confirm profile original file with valid params",async ()=>{
    const res={confirmProfileData: { isSuccess: false }, 
        apiError: undefined,
        }
    mockAxios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(res);
    const response = await confirmProfile(VALID_TOKEN);
    console.log('profile',response);
    expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(response).toEqual(res);
})
```

Result of testing

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/apis/Testing.test.ts
  ✕ Confirm profile original file with valid params (10 ms)

  ● Confirm profile original file with valid params

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      27 |     const response = await confirmProfile(VALID_TOKEN);
      28 |     console.log('profile',response);
    > 29 |     expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                            ^
      30 |     expect(response).toEqual(res);
      31 | })
      32 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/apis/Testing.test.ts:29:28)

  console.log
    profile { confirmProfileData: { isSuccess: true }, apiError: undefined }

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/apis/Testing.test.ts:32:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.857 s, estimated 3 s
```

Mock function has not been called and the mocked value does not resolve or log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your code is not directly invoking the post function on the axios module instance and is instead doing it implicitly via a json parameter, whereas your test mock is looking for a direct axios.post call. There are 2 ways you can resolve this problem.

**1**. Change an implicit post call into an explicit one:

From:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${API_ENDPOINT}${path}`,
    headers: setHeader(contentType, token),
    data: payload,
  })
```

To:

```
axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}${path}`, payload, { headers: setHeader(contentType, token) })
```

**2.** Mock out the axios post call in the test suite set up:

From:

```
jest.mock("axios")
```

To

```
jest.mock("axios", () => {
  const expectedResponse = JSON.stringify({
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
    "issued_token_type": "token-type:access_token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "consumer_profile:read:"
  });
  return () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(expectedResponse));
})
```

This will mock out the implicit post call via a partial mock, however you will not have direct access to the `post` method, hence you will not be able to listen specifically to its calls.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I followed the 1st way by changing the axios post call to explicit one

Comment: But now the mock function is being called, but the data set to mockResolvedValueOnce() is not returned or displayed

Comment: That is because it is a mock. You will need to mock out the result as follows: ```axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(() => expectedResponse)```